# wamp connect to different mysql

Tags: mysql, wamp

WAMP comes packaged with MySQL, Apache, and PHP. I already had a version of MySQL (downloaded from Oracle) installed to my machine with data in it. Is there any way I can make WAMP use the external MySQL rather than the one packaged with it?

For instance, if I click "Restart Services" in WAMP, it restarts the MySQL server packaged outside C:\wamp.

Answer (score 0):

Copy MySQL installed (outside wamp) files to your wamp>bin>MySQL folder. Ensure you keep the MySQL folder name as such without renaming, in the wamp - only then wamp will be able to turn on its services since those values lie in registry.

For example, if folder structure in Wamp is `bin>MySQL>MySQL5.5.8` then copy the files from the standalone installation and copy to `MySQL5.5.8` folder. So ensure you dont rename `MySQL5.5.8` folder.

Now all this wont give you the correct version in phpmyadmin which will require more configuration, it will still show the previous version number as of MySQL that came along with wampserver. But you can atleast be sure inside, in real u r using my damn new MySQL :)

Here is a related question, but dont have anymore info